# How do I NOT encode a string when I marshall it with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have this String that is an html fragment:

```
String x = "<input type='hidden' value='2'/>";
```

I have this object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TemplateResponseBean {

private String name;
private String html;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
@XmlAttribute
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getHtml() {
    return html;
}
@XmlElement
public void setHtml(String html) {
    this.html = html;
}
```

}

I then set the html element as the String x value:

```
templateResponseBean.setHtml(x);
```

when then marshall it with JAXB to create an XML,  it encodes it so the output has & lt;  in stead of <

I understand this is correct behavior, but how do I get it to NOT do that for this particular element?  Im hoping for some annotation that says dont do this.

Comment: You can't.  You've got XML (well, HTML) inside of XML.  On what I'm guessing is the JavaScript side, use decodeURIComponent to get this back into HTML.

Comment: I was afraid of that. The front end people will just have to deal. Thanks!